# ASP.NET / WCF - Execute Server.Execute Asynchronously

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I need to run the HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute method in my ASP.NET application. This application has a WCF operation that does some processing. Currently, I am to do my processing correctly from within my WCF operation. However, I would like to do this asynchronously.

In an error to attempt this asynchronously, I tried running Server.Execute in the DoWork event handler of a BackgroundWorker. Unfortunately, this throws an error that says

"object reference not set to an instance of an object"

The HttpContext element is not null. I checked that. It is some property nested in the HttpContext object that appears to be null. However, I have not been able to identify why this won't work. It happens as soon as I move the processing to the BackgroundWorker thread.

My question is, how can I asynchronously execute the Server.Execute method?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something horribly wrong. You should not be calling `Server.Execute` from your WCF service. In fact, it seems like you don't know the correct way to do asynchronous processing in an ASP.NET application. It's quite different from a desktop application.

See "[Asynchronous Pages in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx)" for a great article that's still relevant.